# Crashing Kubuntu 22.04 in first boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kubuntu, startup, freeze

I have problem with first boot Kubuntu 22.04
Boot going fast, but in last moment he get freeze at logo. I waited almost 15 minutes.

One interesting thing in log file:

**Jul 22 17:12:51 systemd[1]: Startup finished in 4.413s (kernel) + 7.722s (userspace) = 12.135s.**
*Subject: System start-up is now complete*
*Defined-By: systemd*
*Support: http://ubuntu.com/support*

*All system services necessary queued for starting at boot have been started. Note that this does not mean that the machine is now idle as services might still be busy with completing start-up.*

*Kernel start-up required 4413016 microseconds.*

*Initial RAM disk start-up required INITRD_USEC microseconds.*

*Userspace startup required 7722142 microseconds.*

**Jul 22 17:13:17 systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Deactivated successfully**
*Subject: Unit succeeded.*
*Defined-By: systemd*
*Support: http://ububtu.com/support*

*The unit systemd-fsckd.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.*

My system

CPU: Intel Core 2 Extreme 3.0GHz
RAM: 8Gb DDR2
VRAM: NVIDIA GTX 660 2GB
Type BIOS: Legacy (Non-UEFI)

Any ideas?

Also i tried to boot with "nomodeset".

Comment: Just to note fsck is "file system check" usually it runs when your file system gets corrupted, eg if you're disk is failing. First thing I'd do is use smartctl or a partition manager to check your disk health.

Comment: I found one [reference](https://forum.openmediavault.org/index.php?thread/33962-after-updating-to-5-5-7-booting-doesn-t-work/) to a "dead state" error with fsck; are you booting from USB? What hard drives do you have? `blkid` or a partition manager should tell you.